# Items not being added to list using .Add()

Tags: c#, list, deserialization, setter

I have a class named `Model` which contains a property `Elements`. Upon the deserialization of a json, I wish to add the newly resulted object to the list of `Elements` - however, it does not get added.

Firstly, my **Model.cs**:

```
public class Model
{
  public new IEnumerable<Element> Elements { get; }
  public new IEnumerable<Connection> Connections { get; }
}
```

Please note that there are no setters, and I can not add them. This class should remain as it is.

Next, the deserialization and my attempt to add the Elements to the newly created model.

```
Model newModel = new Model();

foreach (var item in jsonResponse) {
   JArray jElements = (JArray) item.Value;
   foreach (var rItem in jElements) {
      JObject rItemValueJson = (JObject) rItem;
      Models.Element rowsResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Element>(rItemValueJson.ToString());
           
      newModel.Elements.ToList().Add(rowsResult);
   }
}
```

I can not instantiate a new list like below:
`newModel.Elements = new List<MEP.Calculations.Common.Models.Element>();`

or assign the `rowsResult` because:

> Property or indexer 'Model.Elements' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
> The property Model.Elements has no setter

Is there any possible workaround for this, except for, as I previously mentioned, adding a setter?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is an iterator; you cannot add to it. Calling `ToList()` creates a new list and will not affect the original `IEnumerable`. You will need to update your `Model` class to allow this to work; either change it to a modifiable collection e.g. `ICollection<T>` or add a setter.

Comment: One option would be to add `private` setters; Json.Net uses reflection so will still be able to deserialise to those.

Comment: You can change `IEnumerable<Element>` to `IList<Element>` in `Model` and then call `Add` on `Elements` to add to it. If you cannot change `Model` class as you have stated then there's no way. By the way `newModel.Elements.ToList()` is turning `Elements` to a new `List` and adding to it. It will not add to `Elements`.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this one! Unfortunately, the `Model` resides in a `.dll` which I am not able to edit. Moreover, I do not think that a change can be supported as it might break some other functionality. Hence, the `IEnumerable` must stay as is.

@JohnathanBarclay, can I somehow add these private setters outside of the `Model` class?

Comment: `Model` has been designed in a way that `Elements` is read-only; so you're trying to use it in a way that the author didn't intend. By doing this you're potentially going to interfere with it's implementation, so don't try to. Is there any alternative to using `Model`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, the workflow is this: Serialize `Model` -> Deserialize the resulted `.json` and then compare them. Now, long story short as it's quite complex - if I deserialize the whole model, `Element` is bugged and gives me an error that it's unable to cast to type. However, this is fixed if I use `TypeNameHandling.Object` when (de)serializing, but this solution is not wanted. So here I am trying to find a workaround.